# Cast certain changeset fields into an ecto :map field

Tags: elixir, ecto, single-table-inheritance

I have a changeset that looks like this:

```ex
%{
  creator_id: "4",
  name: "a test with GraphQL",
  place_id: "13",
  entree_id: "8",
  base: "wheat",
  type: "food"
}
```

My ecto schema is as follows:

```ex
schema "items" do
  field :type, :string
  field :name, :string
  field :data, :map

  belongs_to :creator, Name.SubName.Creators
  belongs_to :place,   Name.SubName.Places
  belongs_to :entree,  Name.SubName.Entrees

  timestamps()
end
```

As you can see, `base` is not a field that is in the ecto schema, I want to cast `base` into the `data` field so that it is a `map` type, ie: `{"base":"wheat"}`. I am using some form a single table inheritance here.

I am trying to add a record to my `items` table. Right now when I read from the table, I cast the `data` field to an embedded schema (depending on the `type`) that contains my `base` field just fine. Where I struggle is getting this field back into the database.

I tried using something like `Ecto.Changeset.cast(params[:base], Map.keys(%{data: :map}))` but obviously that just gets the value which is clearly not a valid map. Additionally this would be painful to specify for all the unique fields that are associated with my other embedded schemas that represent each `type`.

`embeds_one` and `embeds_many` do not apply to this situation because the `data` ecto field represents different embedded schema types. So in this case my question is less about embedded schema use and more about picking out particular fields in a `changeset` and turning them into a `map`. Half of me just thinks I should make a distinct table for each `type` and then I don't have to worry about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can use [`Map.split/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html#split/2):**

```ex
@required_fields [:name, :type, :creator_id, :place_id, :entree_id]
@all_fields [:data | @required_fields]

def changeset(struct, params) do
  {allowed, others} = Map.split(params, @required_fields)
  params = Map.put(allowed, :data, others)

  struct
  |> cast(params, @all_fields)
  |> # ...
end
```

---

Important thing to note here is that this example only works for maps with atom keys, you'll have to modify it a bit to work with both string and atom keys. You might also consider specifying an empty map as the default value for `:data`.

Comment: Thanks! This does the trick... Now I have to decide if this is really something I want to do. Seems a little brittle but it will do for now.